# implement a generic argument method

Tags: go, reflection

I have code in Go, which includes many execution methods.
Each method receives it own struct of parameters.
I want a dispatcher to call each method with its related struct.

The dispatcher receives the name of the execution method, and a JSON of the parameters struct.
Then, it uses reflection to build the struct, and calls the method.

The problem is I get compilation error unless I create the execution methods using empty interface. 
In the example below I have 2 execution methods: api1 is compiling, but is using the empty interface and explicit casting. api2 is what I want to do, but it is failing with compile error:

> cannot use api2 (type func(Api2Parameters)) as type Api in assignment

How can I make api2 usage compile?

```golang
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

type Api func(arguments interface{})

type ApiDetails struct {
    Executor       *Api
    ParametersType reflect.Type
}

var Apis map[string]*ApiDetails

func RunApi(apiName string, data string) {
    api := Apis[apiName]
    parameters := reflect.New(api.ParametersType).Interface().(interface{})
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), parameters)
    (*api.Executor)(parameters)
}

type Api1Parameters struct {
    Count1 int
    Id1    string
}

func api1(arguments interface{}) {
    parameters, _ := arguments.(*Api1Parameters)
    log.Printf("api1 parameters(%+v)", parameters)
}

type Api2Parameters struct {
    Count2 int
    Id2    string
}

func api2(arguments Api2Parameters) {
    log.Printf("api2 parameters(%+v)", arguments)
}

func Test() {
    // this assignment works fine
    var api_1 Api = api1
    Apis["api1"] = &ApiDetails{
        Executor:       &api_1,
        ParametersType: reflect.TypeOf(Api1Parameters{}),
    }

    // this assignment produce compile error
    var api_2 Api = api2
    Apis["api2"] = &ApiDetails{
        Executor:       &api_2,
        ParametersType: reflect.TypeOf(Api2Parameters{}),
    }

    RunApi("api1", `{"Count1":19, "Id1":"a"}`)
    RunApi("api2", `{"Count2":34, "Id2":"b"}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a value using the argument type, unmarshal to that value and invoke the function:

```
var Apis = map[string]interface{}{
    "api1": api1,
    "api2": api2,
}

func RunApi(apiName string, data string) {
    fv := reflect.ValueOf(Apis[apiName])
    ft := fv.Type()
    pin := reflect.New(ft.In(0))
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), pin.Interface())
    fv.Call([]reflect.Value{pin.Elem()})
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IQqAY8TcS8R).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this type-safe, you can push the JSON-to-args conversion a little deeper:

```
type Api func(string)

type ApiDetails struct {
    // Don't use *Api, that's a function pointer-pointer
    Executor       Api
}
```

Then, use a closure to do the JSON translation:

```
Apis["api1"] = &ApiDetails{
        Executor: func(data string) {
            var args ArgsForAPI1
            json.Unmarshal([]byte(string),&args)
            api1Implem(args)
        }
    }
```

With this, you can do:

```
APIs["api1"].Executor( `{"Count1":19, "Id1":"a"}`)
```

You can change the `RunApi` to do something like this.

A second option is to do this using reflection:

```
type ApiDetails struct {
    // Executor can accept any function signature
    // Assume a function with  a single parameter
    Executor     interface{}
    ParametersType reflect.Type
}
```

Then, the RunApi function can use reflection to construct a struct and call `Executor`:

```
    parameters := reflect.New(api.ParametersType)
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), parameters.Interface{})
    reflect.ValueOf(api.Executor).Call([]reflect.Value{parameters})
```

This should work, but you'll only get runtime errors if you mess up.